# Installing Magento2 Theme

Tags: magento2

I downloaded a theme containing the following file:

[image]

In the media files there are these files:

[image]

In the theme files there are these files:

[image]

All these files are very confusing. How can I make this theme work in my Magento installation.

This is my where i have my Magento installed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the theme in magento 2 manually you must need to know about **directory structure of magento2**.

- like for design you need to put files in app/design folder
- like for modules you need to put files in app/code folder
- also for sql file you need to import that sql file in your database
- For images you need to put your images file in pub/media folder

This is one of the best tutorial to learn how to install theme maually in magento2 - https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/crafts-magento-2-theme/

You can also refer below link

http://www.venustheme.com/magento-2-install-theme-quickstart/

http://blog.landofcoder.com/magento-2-install-theme-manually/

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-install-a-new-theme-magento-2.html

Comment: I have seen those, but the problem is I got a really different file structure from my downloaded theme. I would like to know how to do this with the files I got, not with example files like in the tutorial.

Comment: @kevin.a no the theme file structure and the magento 2 file structure both are same , if you have seen in your magento2 route directory you can see there is app folder in that two sub folder code and design , so you need to put your theme code and design folder to magento2 route app/code and app/design folder . same for remaining folders

Comment: So should i overwrite the current app folder? Or just the files in it?

Comment: @kevin.a Currently app folder is blank if you have seen it. by default app folder is blank in magento2 you need to put your theme app/code and app/design folder in your magento2 root folder

Comment: like in theme you have app/design/frontend folder so copy all the files and folder of the theme and paste it into magento2/app/design/frontend. same for app/code and other folders